# jQuery change the button type from any other to "submit" in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-11

I have a string like:

```js
var message = '<button type="custom_type"/>';
```

Then I try to send this string as XML to the server.

```js
$.ajax();
```

And I see this:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

The type of button HTML node was changed from "custom_type" to "submit". It reproduces only in IE11 when I use jQuery.

This code convert string to XML correctly:

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(message, "application/xml");
window.console.dirxml(xml);
```

So the issue is inside the jQuery lib.

I need to send the XML with custom type attribute to server, but I always get `type="submit"`. What can I do to save my custom button type?

Comment: You haven't addressed the obvious question: Why are you using an [**invalid `type`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-button-type) on the button in the first place? It's **always** going to be problematic and, frankly, wrong.

Comment: Also note that your rationale for the claim that jQuery is responsible for this because when you parsed it as XML it didn't happen is suspect. There's a difference between parsing XML and parsing HTML. Your jQuery code is parsing HTML. Your DOMParser code is parsing XML.

Comment: It does seem to have something to do with jQuery. `window.console.dirxml(message);` displays the type as "custom_type" whereas `window.console.dirxml($(message)[0]);` displays it as "submit" (in IE11).

Comment: The reason why I use custom button type is an old client-server protocol.

Answer (score 0):

aside from any other problems you may or may not have, there are only 3 acceptable `types` for buttons:

```
<button type="button|submit|reset">
```

here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

it may be a `jQuery` issue, but it is not guaranteed to handle irregularities, so good luck.  I suggest finding another way.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is just a matter of conserving your custom button type, you can use `.dirxml()` without the jQuery object to do so.

Using this command:

```
window.console.dirxml(message);
```

yields this result in IE11:

```
"<button type="custom_type"/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use $.ajax() to connect to the server. And in this case the button type in the xml is also changes to "submit".

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using dataType:"xml" instead of "text".